# Is "museal" an adjective that you can use?

Tags: word-usage

Briefly, as I think it is a valid word/adjective in French, can we say "museal" to describe to an activity or thing that relates to museums? such as:

> The museal forms of the nineteenth century were radically
>   different than today.

Would that be understandable to native ears? Or does it sound ridiculous? Too contrived?

PS: I'd use museological but I think it relates to museum studies instead of just museums. At least that's how it sounds to me.

PS: I totally edited the word 'formation' into 'form' as I think it caused a lot of misunderstanding. My fault!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you would use museum as an adjective. The museum formations...

Comment: You have the term museology, though: https://www.google.it/search?q=museology+meaning&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIT608IT616&oq=museology+mea&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.6418j0j4&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 - and museological - http://www.thefreedictionary.com/museological

Comment: You can use it if you want. Has anyone else used it? You can search Google books. The word is not in the *OED*. You might want to consider straightforward English *The formations of museums of the nineteenth century...*

Answer (score 2):

To my (native American English) ear, your phrasing sounds unnecessarily contrived. You could simply say "Museums of the nineteenth century were radically different than today." Or, to call out a specific aspect in which museums differed, you could say "Museum collections were different..." or "Museum attendance was different..." or "Museum layouts were different..."

Or if you were talking about how a museums were formed, you could say "In the nineteenth century, museums came into being in radically different ways than they do today."

Comment: Aha! There is a difference between just 'museums' and 'museal formations' here. Every museal form is not necessarily a museum. It can be galleria, cabinets of curiosities etc. At least my intention in making up such expression was because of this difference.

Comment: I love this site...I learn something new every day! Many thanks Reactor4. However I expect that other readers will have similar issues with the word "museal". How about working around it as follows: Organizations such as museums, galleria, cabinets of curiosities, and others were radically different in the 19th century than they are today.